# What is a pA(2) value?

Tags: pharmacology, terminology

I saw this article http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/16710314 and it mentioned pA(2) values and I had no idea what they were. What are they? What do they mean?

If possible it'd be just dandy if you could cite some journal articles/books/other reliable sources for me to dig up.

Comment: I don't know enough about this to write a good answer, but you can find an explanation [here](http://facpub.stjohns.edu/~yoburnb/pages/dictimages/schild1.html). A p(A2) value describes the affinity of an antagonist for its receptor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Digging around a bit, I found a few resources:

[Design and models for estimating antagonist potency (pA2, Kd and IC50) following the detection of antagonism observed in the presence of intrinsic activity.](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/10219974)

and [PHARMACODINAMIC](http://www.ctf.edu.tr/farma/cihatkucukhuseyin/Ing/03_Pharmacodinamics.pdf) on page 30, describes pA2 as:

> indicates affinity of antagonist for receptors

(as Alan Boyd just commented on)

Answer (score -3):

Below are responses generated using the isolated guinea-pig ileum preparation to determine a pA2 value for a sample of the cholinergic antagonist homatropine.
Responses are expressed in millimetres +/- SDM (n =4). Plot the data and then determine by Schild analysis the pA2 value and Schild slope. What conclusions can you draw; does the experiment/data fulfil the criteria for a valid Schild analysis?

Acetylcholine      ACH Alone    ACH +Homotropine       ACH +Homotropine   ACH +Homotrop
Concentration                     3x10^-9 M              1x10^8M            3x10^-8M
[Molar]

3 x 10^-9            3+/-1
6 x 10^-9            8+/-3            Not Response
3 x 10^-8            28+/-6             10+/-4             No response
6 x 10^-8            38+/-8             21+/-9           5+/-2                                                    No response
3 x 10^-7            55+/-5             43+/-7                27+/-9             10+/-4
6 x 10^-7            56+/-5             52+/-3              38+/-7             20+/-7
3 x 10^-6              -                55+/-4              53+/-6             43+/-6
6 x 10^-6              -                   -                56+/-2             54+/-5

Comment: This is a well-written answer; however, it does not answer the question being asked. If you could state what exactly it is as opposed to how it behaves when tested on a guinea pig that would be helpful. Also, it is advisable that you put in references. Aside from this, you did well for a first answer and I welcome you to Biology S.E.! If you have additional questions, please visit [The Help Center](http://biology.stackexchange.com/help).